# Groovy in Jenkinsfile: how to create file and fill with content of byte[]

Tags: file, groovy, binary, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to implement a function like:

```
def writeBytesToNewFile(String filename, byte[] bytes) {

}
```

Which should create a new file and store the contents of the byte array in the file. Now new File(..).setBytes(bytes) doesn't work because the file doesn't exist. Everything I search for seems to be about text files. Some background, I'm downloading a file into the byte[] and try to store that. Another solution would be if I'm able to (http) download into a file straightaway.
Does anyone have a clue how to do this?

Comment: Are you asking how to download a binary file within Jenkins Groovy?

Comment: Well basically yes. Although how to write my byte[] to a new file is also something I would like to know. I already downloaded the bytes into a byte[] var.

Comment: Ok I can answer how to download a binary file within Jenkins Groovy, but I cannot with certainty answer how to write `byte[]` to a new file. For that, have you looked at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#writefile-write-file-to-workspace?

Comment: what's wrong with `new File( './file.jpg' ).bytes = someBytes`? This should create or overwrite the file

Comment: @injecteer it's complaining that the file doesn't exist. When I try that with just groovy it works, inside a Jenkinsfile it doesn't.

Comment: I see. You might want to try out smth like `new File( "${pwd()}/file.ext" ).bytes = someBytes`. `writeFile` is rather text-only and not really suited for bytes